# How can I join in other tables to my LINQ statement and jget selected columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I created this linq statement to get a list of AdminTestQuestions:

```
var adminTests = await db.AdminTests
        .Include(t => t.AdminTestQuestions)
        .Where(t => t.ExamId == examId || examId == 0)
        .Where(t => t.TestStatusId == testStatusId || testStatusId == 0)
        .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(adminTests);
```

The statement works but I need to add two more columns to those that I already have:

What I would like to do is to also get

- `Title` of the question from the 
  Question table and
- `SubTopidId` from the problem table

Can someone tell me how I can extend my linq statement to do this.  What's confusing me is how I can stop linq getting all of the Question and Problem table columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTest] (
    [AdminTestId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTestQuestion]

    [AdminTestQuestionId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AdminTestId]         INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProblemId]        INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Title]            NVARCHAR (100)   NULL,
    [Grade]            INT              NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Problem] (
    [ProblemId]       INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SubTopicId]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [Title]           NVARCHAR(20)    NULL
```

Comment: What columns do you want to return if not everything?

Comment: You say you want to add in more information, but you want to remove some columns in the Question and Problem tables. That makes me think you want to [project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546168.aspx) a new object.

Comment: I just need the Question Title and the Problem SubTopicId columns.

Comment: What about `AdminTests` and `AdminTestQuestions` columns?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I would like to have the AdminTests and AdminTestQuestions columns which I already have. I just need to somehow add the two new columns. The Question and Problem tables have many more columns and I only actually need one additional column from each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you may take is to flatten your AdminTests into a DTO object before you return. This gives you explicit control over how your data is structured and what columns are visible.

First you'd need a class:

```
public class AdminTestDto 
{
    public int AdminTestId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AdminTestQuestionId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionUId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }

    public AdminTestDto(AdminTest a)
    {
        this.AdminTestId = a.AdminTestId;
        this.Title = a.Title;
        this.AdminTestQuestionId = a.AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestQuestionId;
        this.QuestionUId = a.AdminTestQuestion.QuestionUId;
        this.QuestionTitle = a.AdminTestQuestion.Question.Title;
        this.SubTopicId = a.AdminTestQuestion.Question.Problem.SubTopicId;
    }
}
```

Then in your LINQ:

```
var adminTests = await db.AdminTests
    .Include(t => t.AdminTestQuestions)
    .Where(t => t.ExamId == examId || examId == 0)
    .Where(t => t.TestStatusId == testStatusId || testStatusId == 0)
    .Select(t => new AdminTestDto(t))
    .ToListAsync();
    return Ok(adminTests);
```

Comment: I don't see any link to the problems and questions tables in your LINQ. Can you let me know if that's not needed or just missed?

Comment: So long as you have your DB relationships setup correctly, you shouldn't need these. Are you using entity framework or something else? If you're using EF, are you using code first or DB first?

Comment: I am using EF 6 Code First

Comment: Can you include your model classes please?

Comment: I noticed I didn't have the needed mapping set up. It's fixed now.